# Click Image Link - Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to build out a webscraper but for the life of me I can't seem to get this link to click.  I always get an Unable to Locate Element error no matter what I try.  Here's the HTML:

```
<td colspan="2" width="100" height="100">
<a href="place.php?whichplace=desertbeach">
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.kingdomofloathing.com/otherimages/main/map7beach.gif" alt="Desert Beach" title="Desert Beach" width="100" height="100" border="0">
</a>
</td>
```

I'm trying to click the link associated with the a href link.  Tried find element by css, xpath and more but none can seem to find it.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

To click on a link induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following CSS selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="place.php?whichplace=desertbeach"]'))).click()
```

OR XPATH

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@href="place.php?whichplace=desertbeach"]'))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

**UPDATE**

---

The table is present inside and iframe you need to switch it first in order to click on the element.Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and use the css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'frame[src="main.php"]')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[href="place.php?whichplace=desertbeach"]'))).click()
```

Comment: I thought that by running non-headless and by setting that point in the code as a breakpoint that I'd be bypassing the need to wait for it to load, at least during testing.  However your code gave me a TimeoutException with no message.  Do I need to click the parent A HREF for that image and not the image itself?

Comment: @cardinalsfan : Have this resolved your problem or still persist?

Comment: Check if there any iframe present on your page above the table.I am sure there is an iframe.You need to switch that first.Can you share your url?

Comment: Yes, looks like there are iframes.  Link is https://www.kingdomofloathing.com/game.php but you'll need to make an account and log in and progress some portion of the game before the map (and thus the HTML) will look like mine.  This is what I get if I click View Frame Source: https://jpst.it/1Y-vZ

Comment: you just need to copy that iframe tag and paste here

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to do that.  I posted a link to the code I'm seeing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205106/discussion-between-kunduk-and-cardinalsfan).